# Stuck on finding the range of one unknown in a quadratic equation with 2 unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For context this is the question that I am stuck on: Find the range of values of a for which $x^2 + ax + 2(a – 1)$ is always greater than 1.

I have tried to use the discriminant $b^2-4ac$ but to no avail, I am still unable to find the range of values of a as I have two unknowns, x and a in this case. I also tried to substitute different values of x into the equation but realised that it did not really make sense and as I got different values of a each time.

May I know how I can solve this question?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. To avoid confusion, try to change $a$ in $x^2 + ax + 2(a - 1)$ to another variable like $u$ or $p$ as there is also an $a$ in $b^2 - 4ac$.

Comment: Oh I apologise for that, thanks for letting me know. I will indeed keep this in mind for future questions, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: you need $$x^2+ax+2a-2>1$$ or $$x^2+ax+2a-3>0$$ or $$\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+2a-\frac{a^2}{4}-3>0$$
 Note that $\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2\ge0$.

Comment: It looks like you incorrectly transformed $\frac{a^2}4$ to $\frac{a}4$

Comment: @Ingix: Thanks! I stand corrected.

Comment: Hi, is it alright if you could explain or elaborate on your third line? I still do not seem to understand why $(x+\frac{a}{2})^2\ge0$ in this case.

Comment: @Arcane The square of any real number is $\ge 0$. The critical point here is when $x=\frac{-a}{2}$, then $(x+\frac{a}{2})^2=0$ leaving $2a-\frac{a^2}{4}-3>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Domain is the set of possible values of an independent  variable. Range is the set of possible values of a dependent variable so we need to solve for $\space a.$

\begin{align*} 
x^2 + ax + 2(a – 1)&>1\\
x^2+(x+2)a&>3\\
a &>\dfrac{3-x^2}{2+x} \quad x\ne -2\\
x<-2\implies a&>6\\
x>-2\implies -\infty &<a<\infty
\end{align*}

integer solueions of $(a,x)$ are $(2,-1)$ and $(6,-3)$.